# Error : No qualifying bean found for dependency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, dao

I developp a web application with spring mvc 4. for DAO layer, i add a class GenericDAO : `public class GenericDAO {

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

private Class<T> parametrizedType;

public GenericDAO(Class<T> parametrizedType) {
    this.parametrizedType = parametrizedType;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public List<T> executeQuery(String query){
    TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, parametrizedType);
    List<T> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return result;
}

public List<T> listAll(){
    List<T> result = getEntityManager().createQuery("Select t From " + parametrizedType.getSimpleName() + " t", parametrizedType).getResultList();
    return result;
}

public T getById(Object id){
    return getEntityManager().find(parametrizedType, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> executeNativeQuery(String query){
    List<T> result = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, parametrizedType).getResultList();
    return result;
}

public List<T> executeNamedQuery(String query){
    List<T> result = entityManager.createNamedQuery(query, parametrizedType).getResultList();
    return result;
}

@Transactional
public void save(T entity){
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}

@Transactional
public void modify(T entity){
    entityManager.merge(entity);
}

@Transactional
public T find(Object id){
    if(id!=null){
        return entityManager.find(this.parametrizedType, id);
    }
    return null;
}

@Transactional
public void delete(Object id){
    T t = find(id);
    if(t!=null){
        entityManager.remove(t);
    }
}
```

}`

declaring my DAO like below produce an error durring starting my application :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="partenaireDao")
private GenericDAO<VscPartenaire> partenaireDao;
```

error is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency ....: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=partenaireDao)}
```

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)

but it s OK with :

```
@Repository("partenaireDao")
```

public class PartenaireDao extends GenericDAO {

```
public PartenaireDao() {
    super(VscPartenaire.class);
}
```

}

can you tell me what its wrong with my first declaration ?
i don't want create dao per entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> can you tell me what its wrong with my first declaration ?

you were **not** annotated genericDao class,so that class is **not instantiated by spring.**

> i don't want create dao per entity.

then add `@Repository("partenaireDao")` to `GenericDao` class.

Comment: thanks for reply, even if i add @Repository to GenericDAO, i have the same error

Comment: @Repository
public class GenericDAO<T> {
 
 @ PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;
 .....

Comment: i read it,i don't understant, if i add @Repository("partenaireDao") to GenericDao class, what about the others entites ?